# Anonymous custom login with a single guid - why not?

Tags: authentication

I wonder if I might ask for opinions on a simple authentication system I'm thinking about for a pet web site project where the overriding requirement is that the system should have no way to tell who the user is, i.e. have no way of identifying or contacting them.

The system does need to distinguish between these anonymous users of course, and prevent users pretending to be other users.

Perhaps in a strict sense it's not an authentication system at all, more like a distinguishing system.

A simple solution would be to assign a Guid to new users, which gets stored in a cookie/local storage/whatever and used to distinguish them.

Then give the user the facility to copy the Guid, and/or generate a URL that they can bookmark or otherwise store locally, which re-supplies the Guid to the site and stores it as a cookie again - to be used if the cookie is deleted or they want to authenticate from another machine - by using the generated URL or pasting the copied Guid into a 'login' page on the site.

This means there can be no 'I forgot my password' facility; if the user loses their credentials, they are forever lost, that's accepted.

Additionally, if the credentials are stolen, or the user's cookies are compromised, then the credential is stolen forever, there is no way for the real user to lock out the thief, that's also accepted.

Clearly the user would need to make damn sure they store this URL/Guid somewhere safe, that's accepted.

As an aside, there could be a feature that allows the user to regenerate the Guid, which might be used if they accidentally broadcast their Guid somehow, but that also means if somebody steals their Guid and uses the regenerate feature before the 'real' user realises, the real user will be locked out forever - maybe best it's unchangeable so at least if the Guid is compromised, the thief cannot lock out the real user - but this is an aside.

Given the requirement for complete anonymity / non-contactability, and accepting that losing the Guid is like losing a dollar bill, you lose it forever, it seems a reasonable and pleasantly simple solution.

This is essentially the same as having a user/password combination with no email address or other contact details, but more secure than user: sally123, password: mydogsname1968 or whatever just by virtue of it being a Guid, not something the user can remember or easily scribble on a post-it note and stick to a monitor.

It also has the advantage that a user who uses the same machine all the time (and doesn't delete cookies) never has to login or think about credentials at all.

The Guid could actually be two Guids stuck together or three of them interleaved byte by byte, whatever - a unique auto-generated chunk of data that reflects how unnecessarily paranoid the developer is feeling.

Can anyone tell me why this wouldn't be a good solution, given the anonymity/non-contactability requirements and the drawbacks accepted above, or perhaps suggest a better solution.

If it makes any difference to anything, it'll be a Net Core 5 / Blazor Web Assembly / MongoDb application, it's a pet project so doesn't have to pass muster with any client requirements or existing systems etc.

Thanks for any advice/help.

Comment: As long as it is a one-time use, why not? But perhaps you should investigate JWTs and API-based authentication instead. You can easily configure it to require username/password login once (as long as cookies are not cleared), then refresh the token on each visit. This is the most common form of authentication these days for Blazor/WASM.

Comment: Thanks, the intention isn't for one-time use though, and I want to avoid any existing API/OAuth etc and do away with the traditional user/password concept, replacing it with an un-guessable unique-by-definition bookmark that doesn't link you to anything else even slightly - a bit like like the digital equivalent of a physical key to a lock. You can make copies of the key and the lock has no idea who is using the key or which key it was - with the drawbacks that you can lose the key or have it stolen; but the thief cant use their key to lock you out.